# How does the NetBeans C/C++ plugin (CND) create environment for `make`?

Tags: c++, netbeans, makefile

I work with NetBeans for a long time and finally I think I need to know the exact answer for the question below. I asked about that on NetBeans Forum but didn't get any answers - probably because only a person with deep knowledge of NetBeans CND sources can answer it.

My question is simple - how is the environment for `make` created by the NetBeans C/C++ plugin in Linux? In Windows?

I've created a "Project With Existing Sources" (in NetBeans 8.0.2). The project has 4-line Makefile (below) and nothing else.

```
SHELL = /bin/bash
MYENV = $(shell env | sort)

all:
        @echo $(MYENV)
```

When I run this makefile I get a list of environment variables with their values. I'm not posting this list, because anybody can get it easily.

I'm asking this question because I want to adjust this environment according to my needs and I don't see any way to do that now.

Comment: @hyde - yes, I need a way to change the environment for *everything*, which is started via the `make`

Comment: I'm sure this doesn't help the actual goal but anything in the netbeans environment will be put in the make environment (unless netbeans specifically cleans the environment for sub-processes). Also if you can run a script instead of just make your script can set env vars for make but that may also not help you. And those are both workarounds anyway.

Comment: One solution is to set env variables (possibly with a script) when launching Netbeans. Clumsy, but if nothing else works...